# asp.net mvc return actionresult for video

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mp4, jwplayer

What action result should I use when I am trying to return an mp4 video using asp.net mvc csharp?

Currently, I hide my videos behind a method to protect it from unauthorized access. I call these videos from JWPlayer in a web browser. However, the header information seems to be missing or the video is prepared for download and not for playing. Something strange, anyways.

How should I return the file? Should I specify additional headers?

This is what I currently do:

```
return File(path, file.MimeType, fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom ActionResult.

[Here is an example for images](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/13/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx) I used to create one for pdf, the concept should be the same for any file type.